# Variable continuously add up in Update()

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm a newbie.

I'm having a really odd problem here, the filed I defined just continuously add up in Update() function.

This is my code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class MenuManager : MonoBehaviour {

    private int counter = 0;

    void Update ()
    {
        ShowSelectedMenuItem ();
    }

    private void  ShowSelectedMenuItem() {

        if (Input.GetAxisRaw ("Vertical") > 0.9) {


        } else if (Input.GetAxisRaw ("Vertical") < - 0.9) {

            Debug.Log("s Down");

            counter=counter+1;

            Debug.Log (string.Format("counter {0} ",counter));
            Debug.Log("Finish s down");

        }
    }   
}
```

I'm excepting output like these: s Down counter 1 Finish s down

However, In log I got: s Down counter 1 Finish s down counter 2 counter 3 counter 4 counter 5 counter 6 counter 7 counter 8

This is really odd, No matter what I do, I have tried counter++, counter = (counter+1). Makes no different. After the function, counter just keep add up another 7 times but "s Down" and "Finish s down" never showed second time. This script attached to an empty object in a empty project. My editor version is 4.5.4

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the result you wanted by adding this change to your code:

```
else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.DownArrow))
{   
    Debug.Log("s Down");

    counter=counter+1;

    Debug.Log (string.Format("counter {0} ",counter));
    Debug.Log("Finish s down");
}
```

Result:

[image]